# Moving items in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create app that allows to move items inside canvas.

Here is XAML:

```
<Canvas Background="#4CAF50">
    <Grid Background="#3F51B5"
      Width="50"
      Height="50"
      CanDrag="True"
      ManipulationMode="All"
      ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta">
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
private void UIElement_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myEllipse = (Grid)sender;

    Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, Canvas.GetLeft(myEllipse) + e.Delta.Translation.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse, Canvas.GetTop(myEllipse) + e.Delta.Translation.Y);
}
```

Everyting is working fine when I am moving grid slowly. When I move it too fast, the mouse cursor runs out of the grid and movement is stopped. Is there a way to keep cursor in the middle of grid or anything that could help me do it faster?

Comment: Is there a requirement that means it needs to be done inside the Canvas? There is a control/component in a project I work on called WinUX called a DraggableContentControl which might interest you (https://github.com/jamesmcroft/WinUX-UWP-Toolkit/blob/develop/WinUX/WinUX.UWP.Xaml.Controls/DraggableContentControl/DraggableContentControl.cs)

It uses a CompositeTransform to perform the translation manipulation which might be an alternative you could look into

Answer (score 1):

> When I move it too fast, the mouse cursor runs out of the grid and movement is stopped.

This is because you've enabled `CanDrag` property of your `Grid`, this property determines whether the element can be dragged as data in a drag-and-drop operation. You're here designing a Translate-Dragging operation, they are the two different operation systems, and they conflict here.

So a very easy way to make your problem away is to remove the `CanDrag="True"` of your `Grid`. Besides, I suggest here that you also handle the `ManipulationStarted` and the `ManipulationCompleted` events of `Grid` in case other possible problems could occur.

Finally if you're interest in drag-and-drop operation, you can refer to the official [Drag and drop sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop).